# Oracle: Materialized view refresh is not being refreshed automatically

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While I was working on an MV refresh issue, I came to know that Materialized view is not being refreshed automatically though it is scheduled to be refreshed (refresh method: Fast) every day.

Master table is in one DB and Materialized view is in another db and referenced via DB link. I could see that MV stopped refreshing and checked the failure count from USER_JOBS table. I am able to refresh the mv manually without any error. So my question is that is there any way to find out the exact error of MV automatic refresh? Do we have such error table in Oracle?

Oracle version: 11gR2

Please let me know if additional info is required.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be in the database's alert log:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172115/oracle-materialized-view-error-log-table

Bobby